# Kinesis data stream size limits

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I can't find ant reference to a total size of all messages in kinesis data stream in this [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html][1]

is it mentioned in any other place that this value is unlimited